# what is the classification of this stream insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

[image]

This insect I found from Southers region of Bangladesh. Its limbs are larger than its body.and the picture shows its dorsal part.

Comment: This is a Water Strider (Order Hemiptera, Family Gerridae); the end of the abdomen is not in focus, so it's impossible to say if you have an apterous adult (of a subfamily _other_ than Gerrinae) or a nymph; if the latter is the case a species-level identification will likely not be possible.

Comment: Most probably it is Trepobates sp.